# Cat if one new file are generated

Tags: linux, scripting, monitor

I have a script who generate a new file if a new email have arrived  (with fetchmail-procmail) the new email appear in one plain file and I need to process the content of the email if there are one new. 
Example of the log of fetchmail:

```
procmail: [7709] Fri Jul 12 09:10:19 2019
procmail: Assigning 
"LASTFOLDER=Mail/new/1562933419.7709_0.localhost.localdomain"
Folder: Mail/new/1562933419.7709_0.localhost.localdomain 38398
```

I need to retrieve this information only if there are one new mail and process it changing the format of the original recieved file and later copying it to other directory and later clean this original file.

Some easy way to make it?

Comment: I have tested the monitor of the directory script maybe changing the then part can make a cat to the new file to apply the format change.                              filesindir=`ls -t /Mail/new`
for i in $filesindir
do
echo "$listOF" | grep $i
if [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]]
then
listOF=$listOF" "$i
fi
done

Comment: Jww im new in stackoverflow, sorry if the expectating or if Im off-topic.. didnt undestand all here.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Everyone gets a little dinged when starting on Stack Overflow. [MCVE's](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**inotifywait** (part of inotify-tools) is the tool to accomplish your objective:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

Here is a sample script:

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR="/path/to/the/dir/to/monitor/"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE
do
    mv NEWFILE /path/to/newdir
```

More examples here:

https://techarena51.com/blog/inotify-tools-example/